# Is sqlite last_insert_rowid atomic?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, concurrency

I use node.js sqlite3 to manipulate data. I use these codes to insert data to database and get inserted id:

```
db.run("INSERT INTO myTable (name) VALUES ('test')");
db.get("SELECT last_insert_rowid() as id", function (err, row) {
     console.log('Last inserted id is: ' + row['id']);
});
```

I think this is not stable. my db connection is always open. when my server serves this code on multiple and same time connections from clients, Does`SELECT last_insert_rowid()` get id rightly?
Is sqlite last_insert_rowid atomic?
thanks.

Answer (score 12):

```
try{

    db.run("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",data1,data2,data3,data4,function(err){
                    if(err){
                        callback({"status":false,"val":err});
                    }else{
                        console.log("val  "+this.lastID);
                        callback({"status":true,"val":""});
                    }
                });
}catch(ex){
    callback({"status":false,"val":ex});
}
```

this.lastID return the last inserted row id  [By documentation sqlite3 Database#run(sql, [param, ...], [callback])](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback)

Comment: what about that case where multiple insertion occurs in two tables and data of second table depends upon the first table

Answer (score 11):

By documentation [sqlite3 Database#run(sql, [param, ...], [callback])](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback) 
you can retrive `lastID` from callback.

Answer (score 5):

for Node.js Sqlite3 last inserted id you can use lastId

here is a simple Example

```
db.run("INSERT INTO foo ...", function(err) {
    if(null == err){
        // row inserted successfully
        console.log(this.lastID);
    } else {
        //Oops something went wrong
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`last_insert_rowid()` returns the ROWID for the last insert operation on this connection.

The result is unpredictable if the function is called from multiple threads on the same database connection.

Documentation (for the C API):
https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html

If you don't share your database connection (session) between multiple threads for concurrent inserts, this is safe. If multiple threads insert on the same connection, this is unsafe, i.e. you might get either ID or a completely invalid ID.

Comment: Thank u sstn, does using that code within a transaction solve problem?

Comment: @hahamed The relevant documentation does not mention anything like that. The question would be if you are using threads (not supported natively by node.js) on a single database connection for concurrent inserts. That's something only you or anyone with access to the codebase can say.

Comment: I use node.js for serve clients. i did not understand: does concurrent inserts mean threads for node.js?

Comment: `last_insert_rowid()` is protected by transactions. Please note that every client has its own, local database.

Answer (score -1):

`This.data.lastID`  will give you last inserted ID.